# Cloudant replicate all data in android

Tags: android, cloudant

I'm trying to have user registration for my android application. I'm able to successfully make user register and store their details in Cloudant. They can also login using the phone they had used to register.

However, when I try using another phone to login the account, it doesn't work. Is possible to replicate all data from Cloudant so that users can also login to other phones too? Here is my code:

```
public class CloudantConnect {

    private static final String TAG = CloudantConnect.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String DATASTORE_DIRECTORY = "data";

    private Datastore datastore;
    private IndexManager indexManager;

    private Replicator push_replicator;
    private Replicator pull_replicator;

    private Context context;
    private final Handler handler;
    private RegisterActivity register_listener;

    public CloudantConnect(Context context, String datastore_name) {
        this.context = context;

        // Set up information within its own folder in the application
        File path = this.context.getApplicationContext().getDir(DATASTORE_DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatastoreManager manager = new DatastoreManager(path.getAbsolutePath());

        try {
            this.datastore = manager.openDatastore(datastore_name);
        } catch (DatastoreNotCreatedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open Datastore", e);
        }

        // Reach here if datastore successfully created
        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully set up database at" + path.getAbsolutePath());

        // Set up replicator objects
        try {
            this.reloadReplicationSettings();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to construct remote URI from configuration", e);
        }

        this.handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        Log.d(TAG, "CloudantConnect set up " + path.getAbsolutePath());
    }


    /**
     * Creates new document for user details database storage
     * @param user to store user details into database
     * @return document of user details stored
     */
    public User createNewUserDocument(User user) {
        MutableDocumentRevision revision = new MutableDocumentRevision();
        revision.body = DocumentBodyFactory.create(user.asMap());

        try {
            BasicDocumentRevision created = this.datastore.createDocumentFromRevision(revision);
            return User.fromRevision(created);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets replication listener
     */
    public void setReplicationListener(RegisterActivity listener) {
        this.register_listener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Start push replication
     */
    public void startPushReplication() {
        if(this.push_replicator != null) {
            this.push_replicator.start();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Push replication not set up correctly");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start pull replication
     */
    public void startPullReplication() {
        if(this.pull_replicator != null) {
            this.pull_replicator.start();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Pull replication not set up correctly");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop running replication
     */
    public void stopAllReplication() {
        if(this.push_replicator != null) {
            this.push_replicator.stop();
        }

        if(this.pull_replicator != null) {
            this.pull_replicator.stop();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop running replication and reloads replication settings
     * from the app's preferences.
     */
    public void reloadReplicationSettings() throws URISyntaxException {
        this.stopAllReplication();

        // Set up new replicator objects
        URI uri = this.createServerURI();

        // Push replication
        PushReplication push = new PushReplication();
        push.source = datastore;
        push.target = uri;
        push_replicator = ReplicatorFactory.oneway(push);
        push_replicator.getEventBus().register(this);

        // Pull replication
        PullReplication pull = new PullReplication();
        pull.source = uri;
        pull.target = datastore;
        pull_replicator = ReplicatorFactory.oneway(pull);
        pull_replicator.getEventBus().register(this);

        Log.d(TAG, "Set up replicators for URI:" + uri.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Calls when replication is completed
     */
    public void complete(ReplicationCompleted rc) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(register_listener != null) {
                    register_listener.replicationComplete();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Calls when replication has error
     */
    public void error(ReplicationErrored re) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Replication error:", re.errorInfo.getException());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(register_listener != null) {
                    register_listener.replicationError();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the remote database created? The replications will fail if you haven't created the database in Cloudant in your application code.

Comment: Try turning on logging (https://github.com/cloudant/sync-android/blob/master/doc/logging.md#configuring-the-log-manager-programatically); hopefully the messages printed to the console will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got all the code there to do replication. Do you actually call `startPullReplication()` from somewhere?

If you want your `complete` and `error` callbacks to run when replication completes/fails, you will need to add the `@Subscribe` annotation on them both so they're triggered when the events are put on the `EventBus`.

Comment: You're welcome. As a separate issue, if you're replicating the login details of all your users to all the devices, I hope you've considered whether this could be a security risk if users have a copy of your entire user database on their device (particularly on rooted devices).  It may make sense to replicate the user database in some circumstances, but if you don't need users to be able to login to _any_ account when offline, I'd consider checking the login against the server rather than replicating the user database to the phone.